# laravel 5.2 the next 3 events from today

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to set up an event calendar.
The user must see that the next 3 events from today
therefore, when the date is past, the event disappears
how to do? thank you

My controller:

```php
class AccueilController extends Controller {
    public function affichePage() {
        $agenda = Agenda::all()->take(3)->sortBy('date');
        return view('Accueil.Page',compact('slides','agenda'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not being sorted due to the way you are making your call. Here is what is happening at the moment:

```
$agenda = Agenda::all()
```

Load *every* agenda in the database

```
->take(3)
```

From all those agendas I loaded, take the first three.

```
->sortBy('date');
```

Sort *only* those three by date.

To achieve what you appear to want, judging by your request, you would call

```
$agenda = Agenda::where('date', '>=', $the_date)->orderBy('date', 'asc')->take(3)->get();
```

Where *$the_date* is the date you want to be the minimum. Typically, you would use a date function from the Carbon library to do this:

```
$the_date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
```

This query is forcing the work to be done in database, with the call to *get* finally retrieving the results. In order, we are telling the database to:

- Filter all the agendas to only those with a date greater than the one we pass in
- Order the filtered set by the date, starting from the earliest
- Take the first three from that filtered set
- Return that set to the $agendas variable.